# Concatenate number with string in RDLC report

Tags: c#, rdlc

I am using the chart in the RDLC report. I want to Concatenate the "¥" sign with values in X-axis as shown in the below image.

[image]

How I can do this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Use the `+` sign or the `Concat` method.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/specify-an-axis-interval-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15.  You need to add to the string names by using plus sign.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion,but i have tried + sign in the interval but it's not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the answer, this works for me.
Steps:

1. right click on x-Axis and go to the Properties
2. go to properties  - number
3. select custom options & use this expression "¥"#,0

Answer (score 0):

To easily concatenate,right-click to get to the expression phase and type
= "¥" & Fields!ColName.Value
This should work